# If statement breaks with too many conditions

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I've got an if statement like

```
if ( $id == '2781' || $id == '1947' || $id == '516' || $id == '3200' || $id == '237' || $id == '3207' || $id == '3205' || $id == '2647' || $id == '516' || $id = '4571' ) {
    // Do something
}
```

But the if statement appears to be failing because of the number of conditions (as in, it always does something, not just on specified IDs). I can remove a few of them and it works as expected. How would I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you just use a switch statement?

Comment: Also, http://php.net/in_array would be a lot cleaner here.

Comment: Why are you storing that data in your code? Seems like you'll have to release a new version every time another $id needs to have // something done to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is perfect for that kind of situation:

```
if (in_array((int)$id, array(2781, 1947, 516, 3200, 237, 3207, 3205, 2647, 516, 4571))) {
    // Do something
}
```

Also, you had a missing '=' in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
... || $id = '4571' ) ...
```

is assigning value of `'4571'` to `$id`. You have to use the comparison operator:

```
... || $id == '4571' ) ...
```

That's why I like to use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$availableIds = ['2781', '1947', '516', '3200', '237', '3207', '3205', '2647', '516', '4571'];

if(in_array($id, $availableIds)) {
...
}
```